# WooCommerce run custom jQuery script when Add to Cart button is pressed

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to display Materialize framework Toast, when the product has been added to cart. The hook for it is **`woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart`**, or at least I think it is from all the google material I have managed to dig up.

My problem is I can not get it to work. What would be the best approach for that, how would I be able to hook into it.

I have this in my **`functions.php`**:

```
add_action('woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'run_toast_after_add_to_cart');
function run_toast_after_add_to_cart() {
  echo '<a class="btn" onclick="Materialize.toast('I am a toast', 4000)">Toast!</a>';
}
```

But I get:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'I' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: You should show your code so far. Your are more likely yo get help that way.

Comment: You should store for example in a variable `$text = 'I am a toast';` before and then you should use it: `echo '<a class="btn" onclick="Materialize.toast(' . $text . ', 4000)">Toast!</a>';` This way you should avoid the error…

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get it work. The variable did the trick. I ended up adding onclick function to my button in add-to-cart.php